# Suggestions to make cross check between lists faster in Python

Tags: python, numpy, performance

i am implementing a cross check between records: i have a list of record (which is a list itself) and i have to find the best match (with some specific controls like time tolerances, etc) line by line, my current code is something like:

```
def CountOcurrencies(qsoToCheck: list, qsoList: list):
    # Loop in QSOs
    for qsoLine in qsoList:
        # Check if Call and DX matches
        if qsoToCheck[4] == qsoLine[0] and qsoToCheck[0] == qsoLine[4]:
           ...
           # Check if....
             ...
   return resultCode
```

and the main code calls this method for each record:

```
 # Loop for every QSO to get matches
    for qsoIndex in range(len(listValidQso)):
        # Write output of CountOcurrencies to Valid QSO array
        listValidQso[qsoIndex][19] = str(CountOcurrencies(listValidQso[qsoIndex], listValidQso))
```

problem is that listValidQso is a list made of around 60K lists and the complete code takes around 10 minutes. I tried the numpy where to filter a subset of the bit list and execute the method in the filtered list but result is almost the same (most of processing time is used in performing the numpy.where function)
Any suggestion?

I tried using this code in the CountOcurrencies method

```
 # Filter QSO list to save some time
    print("input size: " + str(len(qsoList)))
    npAry = numpy.array(qsoList)
    rows, cols = numpy.where(npAry == qsoToCheck[0])
    filteredQsoList = npAry[rows]
    print("output size: " + str(len(filteredQsoList)))
```

but this filtering takes around 1.5 sec each and the total time is almost unchanged

Comment: If you convert your data into a matrix, you can use matrix operations instead of for loops. matrix operations are much faster than for loops.

Comment: I tried with numpy as i described but is taking the same time, are you referring to a different method?

Comment: For sure you could keep `npAry = numpy.array(qsoList)` and do not repeat it for each row. Next, you may be doing `numpy.where(npAry == qsoToCheck[0])` multiple times for the same value - you could make a function of it and [lru_cache result](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache). Even better, cache only final result -> `len(filteredQsoList)`